# Azure Pipeline Maven build fails with Spring type converter error

Tags: java, spring, azure, maven, build

I try to move from Jenkins to Azure but the build (`mvn clean package`) fails on

`@Value("${xxx.id:#{T(java.util.UUID).randomUUID()}}") private UUID xxx;`

with the following error message:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid UUID string: 607
at java.base/java.util.UUID.fromString(UUID.java:215)
at org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.UUIDEditor.setAsText(UUIDEditor.java:37)
at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.doConvertTextValue(TypeConverterDelegate.java:429)
at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.doConvertValue(TypeConverterDelegate.java:402)
at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:155)
at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterSupport.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterSupport.java:73)
```

On Jenkins and also on my local machine the build completes without errors.
Does anybody know whats going on here, or did face a similar problem?

Java: 11
Maven: 3.6.2

Answer (score 0):

Forgot about this post, but if someone has a similar problem, make sure to check the env variables of the Azure-Agent. In my case the UUID variable had the same name as an internal Azure-Agent env variable so its value got injected..